# Forward port (80) to another local network IP

Tags: camera, iptables

I have a Rpi, which is behind NAT (4G carrier), but I've managed to expose ports to be accessible from the internet using https://www.remot3.it.
I want to use the Rpi as proxy, so I can access a IP Webcam which is in the same LAN as the PI.

The IP Cam is providing web interface on port 80.

How to use the Pi to forward PI:81 connections to IPCAM:80?

Answer (score 2):

Unless the PI is also the default gateway for the camera, you should use some connection forwarding like `xinetd` or `rinetd` or `socat`.

To configure `xinetd`, create a file `/etc/xinet.d/camera_forward` and restart `xinetd`:

```
service camera_forward
{
    disable         = no
    type            = UNLISTED
    socket_type     = stream
    protocol        = tcp
    port            = 81
    user            = nobody
    wait            = no
    redirect        = camera 80
}
```